# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list. Exeption on Sql fed paitent list

Tags: c#

```
if (PatnameTB.Text == "" || PatphoneTB.Text == " " || 
    PatadressTB.Text == "" || PatdobTB.Text == "" || 
    PatgenderCB.SelectedIndex == -1 || PatallergiesTB.Text == "" || 
    PatmedhistoryTB.Text == "") 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Missing Data!!!");
}
else
{
    string Name = PatnameTB.Text;
    string Phone = PatphoneTB.Text;
    string Address = PatadressTB.Text;
    string Dateofbirth = PatdobTB.Text;
    string Gender = PatgenderCB.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string Allergies = PatallergiesTB.Text;
    string Patmedhistory = PatmedhistoryTB.Text;
    
    string Query = @"insert into Paitent.Tbl 
    Values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}')";
    
    Query = string.Format(Query, Name, Phone, Address, Dateofbirth,
                          Gender, Allergies, Patmedhistory);
    Con.SetData(Query);
    ShowPatients();
    MessageBox.Show("Paitent Added!!");

}
```

When i try adding a new patient for testing purposes system refuses to update list but gives me
Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list. Error if anyone can take a look at this I'd be very happy

Comment: Side note: you really need to be making use of parameters other wise you’re begging for an injection attack

Comment: You have a total of 7 strings which you are adding to the query. Your Query strings wants 8. Change Query to `insert into Paitent.Tbl Values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')`

Comment: This `'{7}'` is probably extra. But we don't know your table structure

Comment: Why did you add `oop` tag? what in your code is OOP anyways?

Comment: Thanks for the side note i'm not really intending to use it on anywhere i merely wanted it to be a project in which i made use of sql tables its just a concept demonstrator for future job applications.

Comment: *"well since c# is object oriented i thought it might come in handy"* -- while the language is object oriented, how it is used could be totally non-oop. Please use OOP tag only when you have oop-related questions. Such as design patterns, inheritance, etc. Your question does not contain such concerns.

Comment: @ugurozkan Writing code with major security vulnerabilities, and worse, a complete disregard for those concerns, is a great way to show anyone evaluating you as a potential employee that can immediately move on and start looking at a new candidate.  When writing code to show an employer you want to show the best possible code you can write.

Comment: @Servy Thank you for your insight i'll implement the necessary additions regarding security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong: your format string has 8 slots (`{0}` through `{7}`) but you are only passing 7 arguments.